# How to set table of contents in 2 columns with tex4ht?

Tags: table-of-contents, multicol, tex4ht

This is tex4ht specific question.
I'd like to set table of contents only to be displayed in 2 columns.
Following article given in https://texblog.org/2013/08/14/tidy-and-compact-table-of-contents-with-multitoc/
it works in pdf when compiled using lualatex. But I am not able to make it work with tex4ht. I tried all different options.
Here is MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%

\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}
\renewcommand*{\multicolumntoc}{2}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}

\begin{document}
\title{My book}
\author{Joe doe}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

%this has no effect on changing the output
%\ifdefined\HCode
%\Configure{tableofcontents*}{section}
%\fi

\tableofcontents

\clearpage    
\section{A}
stuff

\section{B}
stuff

\section{C}
stuff

\section{D}
stuff

\section{E}
stuff
\end{document}
```

The result of `lualatex foo.tex` gives

[image]

But when compiled to HTML using

```
 make4ht -ulm default foo.tex "mathjax,htm"
```

gives

[image]

One way I found is this. But it does not look as good as in PDF:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%

\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}
\renewcommand*{\multicolumntoc}{2}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}

\begin{document}
\title{My book}
\author{Joe doe}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\ifdefined\HCode
\begin{multicols}{2} 
{
\tableofcontents
}
\end{multicols}
\else
\tableofcontents
\fi

\clearpage    
\section{A}
stuff

\section{B}
stuff

\section{C}
stuff

\section{D}
stuff

\section{E}
stuff
\end{document}
```

And compiling to HTML using same command as above gives

[image]

the toc is not aligned as well as in the PDF.

When the first example above does not work in tex4ht as is? Is there a better way to do this in HTML?

I have long toc, and I wanted to break it into 2 columns so easier to see.

TL 2020 on Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) CSS property on `.tableofcontens` div:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{ .tableofcontents{columns: 2;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Result:

[image]